# Bitbucket pipeline error "RevisionDoesNotExistException when calling the GetApplicationRevision operation, No application revision found for revision"

Tags: amazon-s3, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

> An error occurred (**RevisionDoesNotExistException**) when calling the
> GetApplicationRevision operation: **No application revision was found
> for revision.** ✖ Failed to fetch revision.

**Below point are checked:**
IAM user access id-key user permission, s3 versioning,
Application and group name, and aws-code-deploy pipeline version change

Code Pipeline:
this is the code pipeline with variables.

[image]

**Error**:
this error during the code deploy step to run in the bitbucket pipeline

[image]

Comment: Please do NOT use images to paste source code nor logs https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557